# Function for creating and populating k6 metrics

Tags: javascript, load-testing, k6

I am trying to create a function in js for k6 tool scripts which would enable me to create multiple type of metrics for "Transaction Name" as input and then create another function to populate those metrics. This will help in avoiding writing similar code for different transaction names and also help keep consistent names of the metric.

```
// line of code to define the metrics
let Search_RT_Trend = new Trend("Search_duration");
let Search_PassRate = new Rate("Search_PassRate");
let Search_PassCount = new Counter("Search_PassCount");
let Search_FailCount = new Counter("Search_FailCount");

// line of code populating the data in metrics
Search_RT_Trend.add(res.timings.duration);
Search_PassRate.add(1);
Search_PassCount.add(1);
Search_FailCount.add(1);
```

Hoping to create two functions which take input for the transaction name possibly as below:

```
CreateMetric ("Search") 

PopulateMetric ("Search")
```

how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```js
function MetaMetric(name) {
    this.RT_Trend = new Trend(`${name}_duration`);
    this.PassRate = new Rate(`${name}_PassRate`);
    this.PassCount = new Counter(`${name}_PassCount`);
    this.FailCount = new Counter(`${name}_FailCount`);
}

MetaMetric.prototype.track = function (req) {
    this.RT_Trend.add(req.timings.duration);
    if (req.timings.duration < 200 /* or whatever */) {
        this.PassRate.add(1);
        this.PassCount.add(1);
    } else {
        this.PassRate.add(0);
        this.FailCount.add(1);
    }
};

let myMetaMetric = new MetaMetric("Search")

export default function () {
    let resp = http.get("https://httpbin.test.loadimpact.com/");
    myMetaMetric.track(resp);
    sleep(3 * Math.random());
}
```

Some things to consider:

- You don't need pass and fail `Counter` metrics when you have a `Rate` one. `Rate` is essentially the ratio between passing and failing, so it's basically those two counters combined :)
- You might find the k6 [checks](https://docs.k6.io/docs/checks) and [thresholds](https://docs.k6.io/docs/thresholds) useful.